# Calculate meetings based on participants, number of meetings and number of groups

Tags: javascript, combinations, permutation

I am building an application in javascript that can calculate meetings with unique groups.

I have this information:

- An array of all participants participating
- The number of meetings.
- The approximate size each group should be. (May be different if it is an odd number.)

All meetings should be broken down into the number of groups.
The goal is that no participant at all has seen someone double.

Does anyone have an idea how I can calculate this? I've been googling for days. I think with some kind of permutation.

Comment: What have you tried so far? You should update the post here with some code that partially works or is narrowed down. Else, this is a very generic question.

Comment: I dont even know how to start